# Determining the type of a function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to figure out the way Haskell determines type of a function. I wrote a sample code:

```
compareAndIncrease a b = 
    if a > b then a+1:b:[]
    else a:b:[]
```

which constructs a list basing on the a > b comparison. Then i checked its type with `:t` command:

```
compareAndIncrease :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> [a]
```

OK, so I need a typeclass Ord for comparison, Num for numerical computations (like a+1). Then I take parameters a and b and get a list in return (a->a->[a]). Everything seems fine. But then I found somewhere a function to replicate the number:

```
replicate' a b
| a ==0 = []
| a>0 = b:replicate(a-1) b
```

Note that **normal, library replicate** function is used inside, not the replicate' one. It should be similar to compareAndIncrease, because it uses comparison, numerical operations and returns a list, so I thought it would work like this:

```
replicate' :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> [a]
```

However, when I checked with `:t`, I got this result:

```
replicate' :: Int -> t -> [t]
```

I continued fiddling with this function and changed it's name to repval, so now it is:

Could anyone explain to me what is happening?

Comment: It seems to deduce 0::Int here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GHCi is a great tool to use here:

```
*Main> :type replicate
replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
```

You define `replicate'` in terms of replicate (I rename your variables for clarity):

```
replicate' n e
  | -- blah blah blah
  | n > 0 = e : replicate (n - 1) e
```

Since you call `replicate (n - 1)`, the type checker infers that `n - 1` must have type `Int`, from which it infers that `n` must have type `Int`, from which it infers that `replicate'` has type `Int -> a -> [a]`.

If you wrote your `replicate'` recursively, using `replicate'` inside instead of `replicate`, then you would get

```
*Main> :type replicate'
replicate' :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a1 -> [a1]
```

#### Edit

As Ganesh Sittampalam points out, it's best to constrain the type to `Integral` as it doesn't really make sense to replicate a fractional number of times.

Comment: Actually, after writing it recursively I got (Ord a, Num a) instead of (Eq a, Num a) because I am using comparison, but your answer is right :)

Answer (score 4):

The key flaw in your reasoning is that `replicate` actually only takes `Int` for the replication count, rather than a more general numeric type.

If you instead used [`genericReplicate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3agenericReplicate), then your argument would be roughly valid.

```
genericReplicate :: Integral i => i -> a -> [a]
```

However note that the constraint is `Integral` rather than `Num` because `Num` covers any kind of number including real numbers, whereas it only makes sense to repeat something an integer number of times.